# Merging two dfs without an on parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dfs that are very similar such as,

dfa:

```
Type | Segment | Rate
IBM      1        .500
IBM      2        .500
MAC      2        .444
MAC      1        .231
```

dfb:

```
Type | Segment | Frequency
IBM      1         45
IBM      2         12
MAC      2         44
MAC      1         66
```

Code to merge

```
dfa.merge(dfb)
```

Resulting output:

```
  Type | Segment | Rate  | Frequency
    IBM      1        .500     45
    IBM      2        .500     12
    MAC      2        .444     44
    MAC      1        .231     66
```

I get output as desired, but my question is how does this merge correctly without an on paramter in the merge code? Thanks!

Comment: When you don't mention on-parameter, it will look for column names which are present in both dataframes and use them for on-parameter internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) documenetation says that,

*'If on is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.'*

Same applies to you if you don't mention the *'how'* param. It defaults to inner join similar to SQL.